# Cystoscapejs UI extensions : Events are not fired (eaten by cytoscape) in custom extension

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have written a custom UI extension by following the procedure that cystoscape.js recommends. I am using jcanvas library to draw shapes on this ui extension. Everything works great except the click events on these shapes (jcanvas library provides events to bind on the shapes drawn)are not working. Click on these shapes makes only cytoscape core click. jcanvas events are not fired because I think cytoscape eats all the events. Could someone please help me to how to listen to events on the canvas which are overlayed using ui extension?

Thanks
Prakash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overlay needs to be on top of the Cytoscape canvases to get events.  Take a look at the existing extensions for examples, like panzoom.

Comment: Thanks maxkfranz. I made some mistake in jcanvas api, that is why I was not able to receive events. But your answer helped me to solve other problems like dragging the shapes